# Rownum in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, row-number, rownum

Is there any way to simulate rownum in postgresql ?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Postgresql > 8.4

```
SELECT 
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS i, 
    e.col1, 
    e.col2, 
    ... 
FROM ...
```

Comment: Be careful.  This is similar to oracle's rownum, but it's slightly different.  Oracle's rownum is assigned at time of reading the row from disk, whereas this row_number() is assigned depending upon what's in your OVER

Comment: What about speed differences?

Answer (score 44):

Postgresql have limit.

Oracle's code:

```
select *
from
  tbl
where rownum <= 1000;
```

same in Postgresql's code:

```
select *
from
  tbl
limit 1000
```

Comment: I would prefer the ANSI SQL:2008 syntax : FETCH N ROWS ONLY (works on Oracle 12, Postgres, ...)
check the doc : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html

Comment: @R.Du I like your comment the best and I think it should be an answer.

Answer (score 42):

I have just tested in Postgres 9.1 a solution which is close to Oracle ROWNUM:

```
select row_number() over() as id, t.*
from information_schema.tables t;
```

Comment: Note that this will not respect an `ORDER BY` in the outer query.

Answer (score 9):

If you just want a number to come back try this.

```
create temp sequence temp_seq;
SELECT inline_v1.ROWNUM,inline_v1.c1
FROM
(
select nextval('temp_seq') as ROWNUM, c1 
from sometable
)inline_v1;
```

You can add a order by to the inline_v1 SQL so your ROWNUM has some sequential meaning to your data.

```
select nextval('temp_seq') as ROWNUM, c1 
from sometable
ORDER BY c1 desc;
```

Might not be the fastest, but it's an option if you really do need them.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a unique key, you may use `COUNT(*) OVER ( ORDER BY unique_key ) as ROWNUM`

```
SELECT t.*, count(*) OVER (ORDER BY k ) ROWNUM 
FROM yourtable t;

| k |     n | rownum |
|---|-------|--------|
| a | TEST1 |      1 |
| b | TEST2 |      2 |
| c | TEST2 |      3 |
| d | TEST4 |      4 |
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9be32/1)

Comment: This was the exact need I had and it solved my issue. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I think it's possible to mimic Oracle rownum using temporary sequences.

```
create or replace function rownum_seq() returns text as $$
select concat('seq_rownum_',replace(uuid_generate_v4()::text,'-','_'));
$$ language sql immutable;

create or replace function rownum(r record, v_seq_name text default rownum_seq()) returns bigint as $$
declare 
begin
    return nextval(v_seq_name);
exception when undefined_table then
    execute concat('create temporary sequence ',v_seq_name,' minvalue 1 increment by 1');
    return nextval(v_seq_name);
end;
$$ language plpgsql volatile;
```

Demo:

```
select ccy_code,rownum(a.*) from (select ccy_code from currency order by ccy_code desc) a where rownum(a.*)<10;
```

Gives:

```
ZWD 1
ZMK 2
ZBH 3
ZAR 4
YUN 5
YER 6
XXX 7
XPT 8
XPF 9
```

Explanations:

Function rownum_seq() is immutable, called only once by PG in a query, so we get  the same unique sequence name (even if the function is called thousand times in the same query)

Function rownum() is volatile and called each time by PG (even in a where clause)

Without r record parameter (which is unused), the function rownum() could be evaluated too early. That's the tricky point. Imagine, the following rownum() function:

```
create or replace function rownum(v_seq_name text default rownum_seq()) returns bigint as $$
declare 
begin
    return nextval(v_seq_name);
exception when undefined_table then
    execute concat('create temporary sequence ',v_seq_name,' minvalue 1 increment by 1');
    return nextval(v_seq_name);
end;
$$ language plpgsql volatile;


explain select ccy_code,rownum() from (select ccy_code from currency order by ccy_code desc) a where rownum()<10

Sort  (cost=56.41..56.57 rows=65 width=4)
  Sort Key: currency.ccy_code DESC
  ->  Seq Scan on currency  (cost=0.00..54.45 rows=65 width=4)
        Filter: (rownum('649aec1a-d512-4af0-87d8-23e8d8a9d982'::text) < 10)
```

PG apply the filter before the order. Damned!
With the first unused parameter, we force PG to order before filter:

```
explain select * from (select ccy_code from currency order by ccy_code desc) a where rownum(a.*)<10;

Subquery Scan on a  (cost=12.42..64.36 rows=65 width=4)
  Filter: (rownum(a.*, 'seq_rownum_43b5c67f_dd64_4191_b29c_372061c848d6'::text) < 10)
  ->  Sort  (cost=12.42..12.91 rows=196 width=4)
        Sort Key: currency.ccy_code DESC
        ->  Seq Scan on currency  (cost=0.00..4.96 rows=196 width=4)
```

Pros:

- works as an expression or in a where clause
- easy to use: just pass the first record.* you have in the from

Cons:

- a temporary sequence is created for each rownum() encountered, but it is removed when session ends.
- performance (to discuss, row_number() over () versus nextval)

Answer (score 2):

Postgresql does not have an equivalent of Oracle's ROWNUM.
In many cases you can achieve the same result by using LIMIT and OFFSET in your query.

Answer (score 1):

use the limit clausule, with the offset to choose the row number -1 so if u wanna get the number 8 row so use:

limit 1 offset 7