# Delete rows of a table specified in a text file in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, file-io, postgresql-copy

I have a text file containing the row numbers of the rows that should be deleted in my table like this:

```
3
32
40
55
[...]
```

How can I get a PostgreSQL compatible SQL statement which deletes each of these rows from my table using the text file?

Comment: maybe useful link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959692/rownum-in-postgresql

HTH.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to perform the delete automatically given such a text file, or do you just need to do it once?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doing it once could look like this:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_x (nr int);

COPY tmp_x FROM '/absolute/path/to/file';

DELETE FROM mytable d
USING  tmp_x
WHERE  d.mycol = tmp_x.nr;

DROP TABLE tmp_x;  -- optional
```

Or use the psql meta-command `\copy`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)

> `COPY` naming a file or command is only allowed to database superusers
> or users who are granted one of the roles `pg_read_server_files`,
> `pg_write_server_files`, or `pg_execute_server_program`, since it
> allows reading or writing any file or running a program that the
> server has privileges to access.
>
> Do not confuse `COPY` with the psql instruction `\copy`. `\copy`
> invokes `COPY FROM STDIN` or `COPY TO STDOUT`, and then fetches/stores
> the data in a file accessible to the psql client. Thus, file
> accessibility and access rights depend on the client rather than the
> server when `\copy` is used.

For repeated use, wrap it into a [PL/pgSQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) with file-path / table name / column name as parameters. If any identifiers are dynamic you must use [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) for the `DELETE`.

If you work with `\copy`, you have to do that in psql in the same session before executing SQL commands (possibly wrapped in a server-side function).

Answer (score 2):

I have a slightly different solution than Erwin's. I would use `IN` because performing a JOIN (USING) it would increase the number of rows that the query will process.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_x (nr int);

COPY tmp_x FROM '/absolute/path/to/file';

DELETE FROM mytable d
 WHERE d.mycol IN (SELECT nr FROM tmp_x);

DROP TABLE tmp_x;
```