# Read data from a text file inside a trigger

Tags: postgresql, text, triggers

Is there any way by which data on an text file can be accessed inside a trigger function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use standard PL/pgSQL functions.

#### `COPY`

For CSV files (or similar) on the db server use [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html). [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html).

> `COPY` with a file name instructs the PostgreSQL server to directly read
> from or write to a file. The file must be accessible to the server and
> the name must be specified from the viewpoint of the server.

For more complex operations you might want to use a temporary table as staging table, `COPY` the file into it and work with plain SQL commands from there. [Similar to this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7663283/939860). Be sure you don't run into conflicts with trying to create the same table in the same session multiple times, though ...

If the file is local to your client and/or you have restricted privileges, consider `\copy` in psql instead. See:

- [Export specific rows from a PostgreSQL table as INSERT SQL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815496/export-specific-rows-from-a-postgresql-table-as-insert-sql-script/12824831#12824831)

#### `pg_read_file()`

There are also [generic file access functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE). For security reasons their use is rather restricted:

> Only files within the database cluster directory and the log_directory
> can be accessed. Use a relative path for files in the cluster
> directory, and a path matching the log_directory configuration setting
> for log files. Use of these functions is restricted to superusers.

I use this to read in small XML files and process inside PostgreSQL. Demo:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_import_from_file()
  RETURNS boolean
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   myxml    xml;
   datafile text := 'path/relative/to/db_cluster/myfile.xml';
BEGIN
   myxml := pg_read_file(datafile, 0, 10000000);   -- 10 MB max.

   -- do stuff, like INSERT ...

$func$
```

You can overcome the path restriction with a symlink from your db directory to any other directory. Be wary of possible security implications.

#### `file_fdw`

You can also use a [foreign data wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-foreign-data.html) to access data files in the server's file system. You need the additional module [`file_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html) for this. Install once per database with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION file_fdw;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. pg_read_file() did the trick for me. Really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you'll need one of the untrusted languages pl/sh, pl/perlu, C etc.

If you explain why you need to do this there might be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my ["PostgreSQL File I/O Functions"](https://github.com/csimsek/pgsql-fio/) extension for basic file I/O.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of this extension, which I offer as a solution to the problem.

Comment: You should add the name of the extension in your answer, and a disclaimer that you're the author of it. Consider also making answer more than just a link.