# Query matching patterns based on an offline table

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, temp-tables

I'm new to PostgreSQL.
I am currently working on a 3rd party PostgreSQL database, and I have limited READ permissions, so I'm unable to create a temp table, or create "user defined" variables.
Moreover, I found that dealing with regular expressions is more difficult in Postgres than MySQL.

Question:
I have the following dummy table:

```
Code   |  Name
11199  |  a
22299  |  b
33399  |  c
44499  |  a
55599  |  c
```

Now I have an offline list (can't create/modify tables in this DB) of numbers.
I need to select the names whose code starts with these numbers - but the return code should be the code in the query statement.

Example list of numbers:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Desired query result:

```
code  |   name
1     |   a
2     |   b
3     |   c
4     |   a
5     |   c
```

I could think of ways to accomplish it if I had more db permissions (such as inserting the list to a table in the database, plus using temp tables + if I could use regex like in mysql), but I don't know where to start on Postgres with this. Help? :)

Comment: [Ain't no such thing as "Postgre"](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines).

Comment: From the link you provided:
"Postgres is also accepted as an alternative name."

;)

Comment: Can there be multiple matches per number in your list? And do you want multiple rows in the result for that?

Comment: That's correct. Notice the difference between "Postgre" and "Postgres"?

Answer (score 3):

something like this:

```
-- using cte as your list of numbers
with cte as (
   select unnest(array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) as Number
)
select c.Number, t.name
from Table1 as t
    inner join cte as c on t.code::text like c.Number::text || '%'
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3d6f4/4)</kbd>**

Comment: Kind sir, I owe you a beer! :)
Thank you, it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Revisit your assumptions. [Regular expressions are a basic, standard feature in Postgres.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) There are also a number of [built-in functions using regex](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER).

But you don't *need* a regular expression here. Use the standard SQL [`LIKE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) operator. See:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

You can provide the list as array and `unnest()` [as demonstrated by Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19482832/939860) or directly with an ad-hoc table using a [`VALUES` expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-values.html). I am *assuming*, that multiple rows can match and you only want a single result per number in your list:

```sql
SELECT n.nr, array_agg(t.name) AS names
FROM  (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) n(nr)
JOIN   tbl t ON t.code LIKE (n.nr || '%')
GROUP  BY 1;
```

#### Advanced solutions for big list

If you have a (big) file holding numbers (and the necessary privileges!), you could utilize more advanced techniques like:

- `COPY` to a temp table
- `pg_read_file()` (for special purposes, needs superuser privileges)
- A foreign data wrapper on the file (`file_fdw`)

Related:

- [Read data from a text file inside a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097854/read-data-from-a-text-file-inside-a-trigger/13098221#13098221)