# How to UPDATE table from csv file?

Tags: postgresql, csv, merge, bulkinsert, foreign-data-wrapper

How to update table from csv file in PostgreSQL? (version 9.2.4)

Copy command is for insert. But I need to update table. How can I update table from csv file without temp table?
I don't want to copy to temp table from csv file and update table from temp table.
And no merge command like Oracle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update selected rows with values from a CSV file in Postgres?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910494/how-to-update-selected-rows-with-values-from-a-csv-file-in-postgres)

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use a temp table? What about a permanent staging tabled (created as `UNLOGGED`), or a db function that uses `postgres_fdw` or `file_fdw` to read from your file and transform the data into your target table?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try it..

The reason that I don't want to use a temp table is..
there are many tables (about 100 tables) to be updated hourly

Answer (score 3):

The simple and fast way is with a temporary staging table, like detailed in this closely related answer:
[How to update selected rows with values from a CSV file in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910494/how-to-update-selected-rows-with-values-from-a-csv-file-in-postgres)

If you don't "want" that for some unknown reason, there are more ways:

- A [foreign data wrapper](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-foreign-data.html) with [`file_fdw`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/file-fdw.html).
  You can run `UPDATE` commands directly using this one.
- [pg_read_file()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE). For special use cases.

Details in this related answer:
[Read data from a text file inside a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097854/read-data-from-a-text-file-inside-a-trigger/13098221#13098221)

There is no `MERGE` command in Postgres, even less for `COPY`.
Discussion about whether and how to add it is ongoing. Check out [the Postgres Wiki for details](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SQL_MERGE).