# How to avoid launching a trigger for every row of a prepared statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, prepared-statement, triggers

I have a `FOR EACH STATEMENT` trigger on `table1`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_table1 AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE OF field1 ON table1
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_trigger_procedure();
```

I have to update rows of that table as follows:

```
UPDATE table1 SET field1='abc' WHERE field5=1;
UPDATE table1 SET field1='def' WHERE field5=2;
UPDATE table1 SET field1='ghi' WHERE field5=3;
...
```

Names and values are simplified for clarity.

Each `UPDATE` is considered a single statement, so the trigger is fired for every one of those rows.

To avoid that, I made a prepared statement:

```
PREPARE my_prep_stmnt AS
UPDATE table1
SET
field1=$1
WHERE field5=$2
;

EXECUTE my_prep_stmnt ('abc',1);
EXECUTE my_prep_stmnt ('def',2);
EXECUTE my_prep_stmnt ('ghi',3);
```

I was expecting the trigger to be fired only after the prepared statement was done, but no, the trigger is fired for every `EXECUTE` row.

The problem is that the trigger procedure takes time to execute.
Any idea to go around this ?

Comment: perhaps this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942258/how-do-i-temporarily-disable-triggers-in-postgresql

Comment: Thanks Andreas, but I considered the option of disabling triggers as a last resort only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide multiple rows in a subquery with a [`VALUES` expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-values.html) to make it a *single* `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE table1 t
SET    field1 = u.field1
FROM (
   VALUES
    ('abc'::text, 1)   -- cast string literal in row 1 to make type unambiguous
   ,('def', 2)
   ,('ghi', 3)
   ) u (field1, filed5)
WHERE  t.field5 = u.field5;
```

You need to cast to a matching type, since the `VALUES` expressions stands alone and cannot derive the column type like in the UPDATE. Unquoted numbers with just digits default to `integer` (`bigint` / `numeric` if too big).

You can still use a prepared statement (with many parameters). For a large number of rows rather switch to bulk loading to a temporary staging table and update from there:
[How to update selected rows with values from a CSV file in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910494/how-to-update-selected-rows-with-values-from-a-csv-file-in-postgres)

More options:
[How to UPDATE table from csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973102/how-to-update-table-from-csv-file/19991203#19991203)

Comment: Thanks Erwin, very useful method, I applied it.