# using pg_read_file read file in desktop PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I wanted to how to read a file in my desk top using **pg_read_file** in  **PostgreSQL**

> pg_read_file(filename text [, offset bigint, length bigint])

my query

```
select pg_read_file('/root/desktop/new.txt' , 0 , 1000000);
```

error

```
ERROR:  absolute path not allowed
```

> **[UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193303/postgresql-save-contents-in-lo-import-to-table)**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using `psql` you can use `\lo_import` to create a large object from a local file.

The `pg_read_file` tool only allows reads from *server-side* files.

Comment: PostgreSQL *server*. Not the `psql` or PgAdmin-III client. It's the PostgreSQL back-end you're connecting to. To see the current directory of the server you can use `SHOW data_directory`.

Comment: @ArjunRaj Please post a new question, rather than tacking on largely unrelated questions to the original.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193303/postgresql-save-contents-in-lo-import-to-table

Answer (score 12):

[pg_read_file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE-TABLE) can read the files only from the data directory path, if you would like to know your data directory path use:

```
SHOW  data_directory;
```

I think that you can resolve you problem by looking to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13098221/1216680)

Comment: **No**, I am using to read `/tmp` and other directories. Use something like `chmod 777` to use any other directory.

Answer (score 1):

To read the content of a file from PostgreSQL you can use this.

```
CREATE TABLE demo(t text);
COPY demo from '[FILENAME]';
SELECT * FROM demo;
```

Each text-line in a SQL-ROW. Useful for temporary transfers.

Answer (score 0):

lo_import(file path) will generate an oid.This may solve your problem. you can import any type of file using this (even image)