# PostgreSQL : save contents in lo_import to table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

[Main question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074987/using-pg-read-file-read-file-in-desktop-postgresql)

I wanted to read a file in my desktop using lo_import in PostgreSQL

How to insert content in to a table  using this function and  display later

```
SELECT lo_import('/root/desktop/new.txt');
```

out put

```
18767
```