# Trying to copy text file to table postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Trying to save a text file from desktop

```
copy my_notes(notes) from  '/root/desktop/test_note.txt'
```

It shows this error..

> ERROR:   extra data after last expected column
>
> CONTEXT:  COPY my_notes, line 3: "    cher"

I'm a newbie  in postgresql

Answer (score 2):

`COPY` expects tab-separated data, with newlines separating rows.

It isn't suitable for just loading a text file into a field. To do that, I suggest using a simple script, say `python` and `psycopg2`.

Answer (score 0):

To read a plain text from a file, there is also `pg_read_file()` - reserved for superusers, though, because of potential security implications. Details in this related answer:
[Read data from a text file inside a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097854/read-data-from-a-text-file-inside-a-trigger/13098221#13098221)