# Read binary file with PostgreSQL without pg_read_file

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I need a solution to the following problem with a clear PostgreSQL 9.4:

- *Read a zipped file from server into a bytea column*
- *No extensions allowed*
- *Superuser allowed*
- *Postgres user has permission to read the file*
- *Can be a user function*

**EDIT:**

The file is outside cluster path, so normal functions raise:
*SQL Error: ERROR:  absolute path not allowed*

Comment: Why did you copy/paste your previous deleted answer when you can just undelete it? Also, keep in mind that you cannot reward your bounty to your answers.

Comment: I tried to undelete, but no enough votes are issued to restore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple function `get_file_contents(filename text) returns bytea` for the job.

```sql
create or replace function get_file_contents(filename text) returns bytea as
$fn$
 declare 
    lo_oid oid;
    retval bytea;
 begin
    lo_oid := lo_import(filename);
    retval := lo_get(lo_oid);
    perform lo_unlink(lo_oid);
    return retval;
 end;
$fn$ language plpgsql;
```

- Trivial usage

```sql
-- Read the great work of Sun Tzu
select get_file_contents('/media/data/ForeignData/The Art Of War.pdf');

-- Insert into a table, update a table
insert into mytable (mycolumn[,<others>]) values (get_file_contents(myfilename)[,<others>]);
update mytable set mycolumn = get_file_contents(myfilename) where <whatever there>;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a better version than mine and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in function **`pg_read_binary_file()`**. It's available since Postgres 9.1 and does exactly what you want. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE-TABLE)

> Returns all or part of a file. This function is identical to
> `pg_read_file` except that it can read arbitrary binary data,
> returning the result as `bytea` not `text`; accordingly, no encoding
> checks are performed.
>
> This function is restricted to superusers by default, but other users
> can be granted `EXECUTE` to run the function.

So to ...

> Read a zipped file from server into a `bytea` column

```sql
UPDATE custom_table
SET    content = pg_read_binary_file('/tmp/28528026bc302546d17ce7e82400ab7e.zip')
WHERE  id = 123;
```

Considerably faster than any workaround.

Note this restriction, quoting [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE):

> Only files within the database cluster directory and the log_directory
> can be accessed. Use a relative path for files in the cluster
> directory, and a path matching the log_directory configuration setting
> for log files.

You can overcome the path restriction with a symlink from your db directory to any other directory. Be wary of possible security implications, though. See:

- [Read data from a text file inside a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097854/read-data-from-a-text-file-inside-a-trigger/13098221#13098221)

Also, consider upgrading to a current version of Postgres [Postgres 9.4 has reached EOL on February 13, 2020](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

Comment: Yep, I tried. But for some unknown reason the field is not loaded with the file contents...

Comment: I don't own the database, it's belongs some Gov. Department. By the away this request was filled.

Comment: nope. The field just remains empty using normal methods. The most strange part is that the contents are shown using simple Select. But fails when used with Insert or Update. I can't put the database into deep trace mode, because its accessed by more than 40.000 users daily.

Comment: You are aware of this bit from the manual? `Only files within the database cluster directory and the log_directory can be accessed. Use a relative path for files in the cluster directory, and a path matching the log_directory configuration setting for log files.` Also, upgrading the Postgres version might help.

Comment: Generally, if it works in a `SELECT`, it should also work in an `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. That sounds *very* odd. To be sure: use `pg_read_binary_file()`, not `pg_read_file()`.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot o research, I came out with the following function:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION file_read(file text)  
  RETURNS bytea AS $$
    DECLARE
      content text;
      tmp text;
    BEGIN
      file := quote_literal(file);
      tmp := quote_ident(md5(random()::text));

      -- create tmp table using random name
      EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMP TABLE ' || tmp || ' (id oid, file_name text, content bytea)';
      
      -- add given filename
      EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO '|| tmp ||' (file_name) VALUES('|| file ||')';
            
      -- add the document to large object storage and return the link id
      BEGIN
           EXECUTE 'UPDATE ' || tmp || ' SET id = lo_import(file_name) ';
      EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
           RETURN NULL;
      END;
            
      -- pull document from large object storage
      EXECUTE 'UPDATE ' || tmp || ' SET content = lo_get(id) ';
      
      -- delete the file from large object storage
      EXECUTE 'SELECT lo_unlink(id) FROM ' || tmp;
      
      -- save data to content variable
      EXECUTE 'SELECT content FROM ' || tmp INTO content;
      
      -- drop tmp table      
      EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE ' || tmp;

      -- return 
      RETURN content;
    END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Sample use case :

Read from file
`select file_read(concat('/tmp/', '28528026bc302546d17ce7e82400ab7e.zip')`

Update column
`update custom_table set content = file_read(filename)`