# Strip first whitespace importing csv data

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I would like to import data into my postgresql table.
I have .csv file that is formated like this:

```
1; John Blake
2; Roberto Young
3;Mark Palmer
```

Any solution how to strip first whitespace where it exists?

i used following code

```
\copy users from 'users.csv' using delimiters E';'
```

And it does keep whitespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COPY` to a temporary staging table and `INSERT` into the target table from there, trimming the text column.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_x AS
SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 0;   -- empty temp table with structure of target

\copy tmp_x FROM '/absolute/path/to/file' delimiters E';'; -- psql command (!)

INSERT INTO users
      (usr_id,       usr,  ...) -- list columns
SELECT usr_id, ltrim(usr), ...
FROM   tmp_x;

DROP TABLE tmp_x;  -- optional; is destroyed at end of session automatically
```

[`ltrim()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) only trims space from the left of the string.

This sequence of actions performs better than updating rows in the table after `COPY`, which take longer and produce a dead rows. Also, only newly imported rows are manipulated this way.

Related answer:
[Delete rows of a table specified in a text file in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659008/delete-rows-of-a-table-specified-in-a-text-file-in-postgres/7663283#7663283)

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use COPY alone to do that.

You can use an UPDATE coupled with [trim](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html):

```
UPDATE table SET column = trim(from column)
```

Or use a script to clean the data before bulk inserting the data to the DB.