# Create auto-Increment column in resultset PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

The result of this query is only meaningful if the order from `path` is preserver. However, upon my Left Inner Join the result is scrambled. I was thinking that I could just create a new column in the resultset that is just like an index of the result and then as the final clause of the entire sql add an `ORDER BY idx`.

This is my query without trying to preserve the final order:

```
SELECT path.*, network_link.v0prt
    FROM (SELECT *                              // Need order preserved from this one
        FROM shortest_path_shooting_star(
        'SELECT gid as id, source::integer,
        target::integer, distance::double precision as cost,
        x1, y1, x2, y2, rule, to_cost FROM
            network_link as net ORDER BY net.gid', 9, 1, false, false)) as path
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT gid, v0prt FROM network_link) as network_link 
    ON (network_link.gid=path.edge_id);
```

Any insight would be great.

Thanks.
And my attempt to add an indexing value and ORDER BY (which doesn't work).

```
SELECT path.*, network_link.v0prt
    FROM (SELECT incr(0) as idx, * 
        FROM shortest_path_shooting_star(
        'SELECT gid as id, source::integer,
        target::integer, distance::double precision as cost,
        x1, y1, x2, y2, rule, to_cost FROM
            network_link as net ORDER BY net.gid', 9, 1, false, false)) as path
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT gid, v0prt FROM network_link) as network_link 
    ON (network_link.gid=path.edge_id)
ORDER BY idx;
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959692/rownum-in-postgresql

Comment: @dezso I have an order inside the inner select.

Comment: @dezso It's sorted by gid.  The function is from pgRouting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To preserve the order returned by `shortest_path_shooting_star` (if it gives no other way), you can use the window function `row_number` to keep track of the original order, and them `ORDER BY` its result:

```
SELECT path.*, network_link.v0prt
    FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER() AS row_number, *
        FROM shortest_path_shooting_star(
        'SELECT gid as id, source::integer,
        target::integer, distance::double precision as cost,
        x1, y1, x2, y2, rule, to_cost FROM
            network_link as net ORDER BY net.gid', 9, 1, false, false)) as path
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT gid, v0prt FROM network_link) as network_link 
    ON (network_link.gid=path.edge_id)
ORDER BY path.row_number;
```

**UPDATE:**

From PostgreSQL version 9.4 and newer, a better method would be using [`WITH ORDINALITY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS):

```
SELECT path.*, network_link.v0prt
FROM shortest_path_shooting_star(
        'SELECT gid as id, source::integer,
        target::integer, distance::double precision as cost,
        x1, y1, x2, y2, rule, to_cost FROM
            network_link as net ORDER BY net.gid', 9, 1, false, false)
) WITH ORDINALITY AS path
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT gid, v0prt FROM network_link) as network_link 
    ON (network_link.gid=path.edge_id)
ORDER BY path.ordinality;
```

Comment: Yes this was what I was aiming for originally. Also as Wrikken stated earlier - this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!