# How to add numbers to grouped rows in postgresql group by clause

Tags: postgresql, group-by, row

I have a PostgreSQL table, containing duplicate values in a text column. It looks like this:

```
gid, capt
1, foo
2, foo
3, bar
4, bar
5, bar
6, buz
7, buz
```

I need to add a column with distinct numbers for each value in a group, so my table should look like this:

```
gid, capt, rnum
1, foo, 1
2, foo, 2
3, bar, 1
4, bar, 2
5, bar, 3
6, buz, 1
7, buz, 2
```

It's a kind of a row number inside each group, always starting from 1. Can anyone please provide me with an appropriate SELECT statement?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

With help from [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959692/rownum-in-postgresql):

```
SELECT gid, capt, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY capt ORDER BY gid) AS rnum
FROM your_table_here ORDER BY gid;
```

The `row_number` [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html) provides the count.

The `PARTITION BY` statement in the `OVER` clause tells the database to restart its numbering with each change to `capt`. The `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause tells the database to count along with the gid column.

Comment: Thanks for PARTITION BY tip, but why do I need an ORDER BY gid ?

Comment: Try it without. I assume you mean the `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause: without that, the DBMS doesn't know to count along with the `gid` column. It will "choose" an arbitrary order for its number within each `capt` partition, which, likelier than not, will not be what you're after.

Comment: @mofoyoda: see [tutorial in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select gid, 
       capt, 
       row_number() over (partition by capt order by gid) as rnum
from the_table
order by capt, gid;
```