# Converting rownum from Oracle to Postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql, limit, rownum

I need to make a conversion from Oracle SQL to PostgreSQL.

```
  select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.table1Id
  where table1.col1 = 'TEST' 
  and rownum <=5
  order by table2.col1
```

If I delete `and rownum <=5` and put at the end `limit 5`, there are differences between the 2 dialects. In Oracle, first are selected the 5 elements, and after that, they are sorted by `table2.col1` .
 In Postgres, first all the list is sorted, and AFTER there are selected the first 5 elements.

How can I obtain the same result in Postgres as in Oracle?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959692/rownum-in-postgresql

Comment: Since the result in Oracle is basically random - there is no reliable way to predict which 5 rows will be selected - it's probably impossible to ensure that a query returns the same results on both systems.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version you are using, PostgreSQL 8.4 and above have [Window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html). Window function **ROW_NUMBER()** is capable of implementing the functionality of Oracle pseudo column rownum.

```
select row_number() over() as rownum,* from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.table1Id where table1.col1 = 'TEST' and rownum <=5 order by table2.col1;
```

Comment: Although note window functions are not allowed in the WHERE clause, as OP wants to do

Comment: @harmic: you can always put the select with the `row_number()` into a derived table and then use the column alias in the `where` clause.

Comment: As per a_horse_with_no_name's comment, if you want to use window functions like that you have to put them in a derived table (ie. subquery in FROM clause). It's not enough to just use an alias within the same query.

Comment: Today I met another situation, with the same order by: if in  "select" i put "table1.col1, table2.col2" , and not " * ", the subselect does not work in this case for Postgres, because table2.col1 is not in the columns selected.

Answer (score 1):

To get the behavior you desire, you can use a subquery like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT table1.col1 as t1col1, table2.col1 as t2col1 
    FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1Id
    WHERE table1.col1 = 'TEST'
    LIMIT 5
) AS sub
ORDER BY t2col1;
```

I named the columns there because in your example both tables had a col1.

Note however that without any ordering on the inner query, the selection of 5 rows you get will be purely random and subject to change.