# How to add counting rows to query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have this query:

```
select id, name
from users
```

and it gives:

```
120 jack
130 jason
138 ban
```

How do I change the query so it will auto assign increasing row number and gives:

```
 1   120 jack
 2   130 jason
 3   138 ban
```

Comment: are you looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959692/rownum-in-postgresql)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to give rows a number, you'd use ROW_NUMBER().

```
select row_number() over (order by id), id, name
from users
order by id;
```

Notice that you state the same order twice, once for the numbering, once for the output order.